# Hybrid Application (Cordova Library - Phonegap Plugin) Crashes on iOS 7 while loading Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, cordova, ios7, phonegap-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I am developing a hybrid application. My application is having a locator module that loads Google maps and drops the pins at some particular location. I am using a geolocation javascript file (Cordova) and phonegap location plugins to load the map.

But when I run my application on a device with iOS7 version, the app crashes after some time. When I connected the device and checked the crash logs, I came to know that it was due to increased memory usage after a certain time (while using the google maps module).

I want to know if I can increase the limit of memory usage by my application as it gets crashed when its memory usage goes high. Also, as this is a hybrid app so need to check if this can be done through native.

Comment: I'm having the same problem using the Google Maps JavaScript API in the standard web view.  I'm hoping clearing the application cache in the WebView controller might solve this issue -- can you provide any details on your implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Heyy... the problem is solved. Posting the answer to my own question so that others may also implement it if they ever come across such issue.
.

I cleared the application caches in "didReceiveMemoryWarning" method of my view controller and custom plugins and set the properties and variables to NIL in "onMemoryWarning" method of CDVPlugin class. And this approach did the work for me. I am not getting any crash as of now.
Hope this helps the programmers facing similar issue !!!!

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about this solution? Do you add your code in native part or it is using javascript?

Comment: The map was loaded from a java script but the GPS handing prompt was done natively.

Comment: how did you clear the caches in "didReceiveMemoryWarning"? Setting properties and variables didn't affect other code? They might be holding some values. Little explanation will be very helpful.